# ActiveAdmin use custom method to filter data and match data present in the parent table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ransack

I have bookings table which belongs to user and in my activeadmin booking resource I am displaying user by bookings.user.email and added the users filter as

```
filter :user_email, as: :string
```

But I want a custom ransack method for user email which strips the input value to remove surrounding white space in the filter email field. How should I do this with ransack

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in Ransack. You could however add a `controller do` block to the active admin resource like so:

```
controller do
  before_action :strip_whitespace_params
  def strip_whitespace_params
    params["q"]["user_email_contains"].try(:strip!)
  end
end
```